# Trouble going from Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: c

I just started learning C today so this might seem like a simple question but I'm having trouble running my program. I'm trying to implement a program that converts from Celsius to Fahrenheit. The formula for converting from Celsius to Fahrenheit is T(F)=T(C)*9/5+32. The degrees In Celsius is given as 30.

```
int main()
{
    int DegreesCelsius;
    printf("30 Degrees Celsius:");
    scanf("%d",&30 );
    printf("The temperature in F is %d\n", 30 * 9/5 + 32);

    return 0;
}
```

My work is shown above. The problem is on the line containing `scanf` where I'm told "1value required as unary & operand"

Am I using the ampersand incorrectly?
Thanks

Comment: In that case you don't need a `scanf`, just `printf("The temperature in F is %d\n", (int)(30 * 9/5 + 32));` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to scan the entered value into `DegreesCelsius`, and then use that variable to perform the conversion.

```
int DegreesCelsius;
printf("Degrees Celsius: ");
scanf("%d", &DegreesCelsius);
printf("The temperature in F is %d\n", DegreesCelsius * 9/5 + 32);
```

`&30` is invalid syntax, as `30` is an integer literal and cannot be addressed by `&`; this is why you have `DegreesCelsius`, to hold the value the user enters.